# How to use jest & enzyme to test code splitting (code splits at the routes level using react-loadable)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-loadable

I have a React project where I am using `react-loadable` to split a code at the route level. I’m also using Redux to manage the app’s store.

What I'm looking for is the way I can use Jest & Enzyme in order to test my routes (for the routes I’m using `connected-react-router` and `react-loadable` for splitting code).

- **An example of the route below:**

  ```js
  import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
  const AsyncExampleScreen = Loadable({
      loader: () => import("ExampleScreen"),
      loading: LoadingComponent
  });
  <Route 
      exact 
      path='/' 
      component={AsyncExampleScreen} 
  />
  ```
- **My index.js:**

  ```js
  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
  import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  import configureStore, { history } from 'store';
  import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
  import App from 'App';
  const STORE = configureStore();
  const render = () => {
       ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={STORE}>
             <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <App />
             </ConnectedRouter>
          </Provider>,
          document.getElementById('root')
      );
  }
  render();`
  ```
- **Example of a test (in the case I’m not using `react-loadable` for splitting at the route level)**

  ```js
  import React from 'react';
  import { mount } from 'enzyme';
  import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
  import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  import configureStore, { history } from 'store';
  import App from 'App';
  import Example from 'ExampleScreen';
  const STORE = configureStore();
  describe('routes using memory router', () => {
      it('should show Home component for route /', () => {
        const component = mount( <MemoryRouter initialEntries = {['/']} >
          <Provider store={STORE}>
              <App />
          </Provider>
       </MemoryRouter>
      );
      expect(component.find(Example)).toHaveLength(1);
      })
  })
  ```